# How to disable some pages in second language

Tags: prestashop, multilingual

I'm developing a website with Prestashop and I added a Blog module.

My website is available in 2 languages (English and French) but my blog posts will only be available in French.

How can I delete the pages I don't want in English ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

- **Add a permanent redirection** in your .htaccess file to another page (which will explain that this content is not available in English), example:

  `Redirect 30 /blog/en/ http://www.myshop.com/not-available-in-english.html`

  You can read more about 301 redirects [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/).

*-or-*

- **Edit your Blog module Smarty template** file (.tpl) and add encapsulate the existing code within an {if} statement based on the user's language, example:

  `{if $lang_iso == 'en'}
      {l s='Sorry, this content is not available in English.'}
  {else}
  ... Existing code here
  {/if}`

Answer (score 0):

Or try with in htaccess rule :

```
Redirect 301 /blog/en/(.*) http://www.myshop.com/fr/$1
```

Regards